# Can't get full 60Hz at native 3840x2160 resolution?

Tags: windows-10, resolution, displayport, display-settings, 4k-resolution

I just built a new workstation, equipped with an EVGA GTX 1080 and an ASUS PA328Q monitor with Windows 10 OS. I've installed the most recent drivers for both, however in the display adapter properties, there is no mode for "3840 by 2160, True Color (32 bit), 60 Hertz" in the List All Modes window.

The GeForce GTX 1080 spec claims it should be able to support 8K resolution at 60Hz, and EVGA's page specifies:

> 240Hz Max Refresh Rate
>
> Max Digital : 7680x4320

http://www.evga.com/Products/Product.aspx?pn=08G-P4-6183-KR

The ASUS PA328Q specs also claim to support it:

> 3840 x 2160 at 60Hz (DisplayPort1.2)
> 3840 x 2160 at 60Hz (HDMI-1 port)
> 3840 x 2160 at 30Hz (HDMI-2 and HDMI-3 ports)
> 3840 x 2160 at 30Hz (MHL3.0)

http://www.asus.com/us/Monitors/PA328Q/specifications/

I'm using DisplayPort to connect the display.

Is this a common problem? Is there something that might need to be done to enable full-resolution/full-refresh support?

Answer (score 4):

Turns out the ASUS PA328Q treats its DisplayPort interfaces as DisplayPort 1.1 by default, and instead of detecting DisplayPort 1.2 support on the other end (if that's possible) it exposes the DisplayPort standard as a setting that must be changed by the user. After setting the interface to DisplayPort 1.2, the "3840 by 2160, True Color (32 bit), 60 Hertz" mode is available.

Comment: where have you changed this? In the monitor menu? Driver setting in Windows?

Comment: It was a setting on the monitor itself. I don't know whether the DisplayPort standard is actually capable of supporting the type of discovery that I had assumed would exist, but if it doesn't then this might be common for this to be a monitor setting.

Comment: ok, thanks. It would be nice if you would post a picture of the setting.